# `null` result from request in servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new in servlets-

I am filling text in form but value in request is null-

> In login page-

```
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="text" name="pwd">
<a href="display.jsp">link</a>
</form>
</body>
```

[image]

> In DisplayPage-

```
<body>
Display:
<%
String uname=(String)request.getParameter("uname");
String upass=(String)request.getParameter("pwd");
out.println(uname+" - "+upass);
Enumeration<String> enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
boolean b=enumeration.hasMoreElements();
out.println(b);
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    String data=(String)request.getParameter(name); 
    out.println(name+" - "+data);   
}

%>
</body>
```

[image]

Now in my result value of `uname` and `upass` is `null` and hence `boolean` `b` is `false`.Weird!

**My Question Is-** If request object is created when we use `anchor tag` since there is no `NPE` on calling `getParameter()` on `request` object,so what kind of data attached with this `request` object.why this is provided to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are `not submitting` your `form` to server or not passing `any value in url`, instead you are clicking on link, which will redirect it to your link.

```
<body>
<form action="display.jsp"> // added action
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="text" name="pwd">
<button type="submit">Link</button> // added submit button
</form>
</body>
```

**For Updated Question**

On server side every request is handled as `HttpServletRequest` object. So when we submit the form, every input field is submitted and then it is retrieved from the request object on server side.

Comment: but anchor tag creates request object like form submittion

Comment: Yes, that won't contain your textbox values.

Comment: means request object crated by `anchor tag` creates `request` object,but dont have values for text,my question is what kind of data we can pass by it without `rewriting url`

Comment: `Without rewritting url`, I did not get you what you are asking?

Comment: MEANS WITHOUT DOING THIS- `<a href='display.jsp?uname="+n+"'>link</a>`

Comment: Why don't you try the code I have provided in my answer.